# How to pass parameters to the index function of default controller in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, parameters

In my Codeigniter project, I need to generate URLs like this `example.com/username`. Here 'username' is a parameter to the default controller 'Home'.

I am using remap to pass params to the default controller's index function.

```
 function _remap($param)
 {
    $this->index($param);
 }
```

I am working on a CodeIgniter project. I have a default controller as 'Home'.
My site URL is example.com. What I need to do is pass the parameter to the default controller 'Home' so I can show profiles like this:

```
example.com/username
```

But I can't use this URL. The only way I can pass the parameters to the default controller and make it work is to show the default controller in the URL.
like  example.com/home/username.   Which is not what I need.

I need the default controller not to show in the URL and generate URLs like `example.com/username`.

Answer (score 0):

`index()` in the default `Home` controller will be like

```
 public function index($params = ''){
    echo $params;
 }
```

calling `index()` here

```
 function _remap($param)
 {
    $this->index($param);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for trying but that's exactly how it is right now.

Comment: So, where you are facing problem?

Comment: when I do this the URL becomes example.com/home/username.  when I remove home (Default controller) then it throws a 404 error. I need the URL to be example.com/username.

Comment: Why you are not using route?

Answer (score 0):

in your config/config.php file. define your url.and then define route for parameters.

```
 $config['base_url'] = 'example.com';
```